# React router component can't render its own children?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm trying to embrace the react-router 4 philosophy of having routing spread throughout the app instead of one central place. For brevity, <**App**> effectively spits out the following in its **render**():

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Link to='/' />
    <Link to='/linkb' />
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={ComponentA}>
        <Route exact path='/linkb' component={ComponentB>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

...
So far so good: the nav links help me to route to the corresponding components A and B and my 2 page app works fine.

The problem I'm having is that, inside componentB, now I want it to have its own child routes. Though these routes will be 'grandchildren' of `<App/>`, I see no reason why `<App/>` should know or care about them. I built this (surrounding content and css stuff mostly ripped out for clarity):

## **Component B**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ComponentC from './ComponentC';
import ComponentD from './ComponentD';

export default class ComponentB extends Component {
  constructor(props) { super(props);}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Link to='/linkb/c' className='btn'>link C</Link>
          <Link to='/linkb/d' className='btn'>link D</Link>
        </div>
        {this.props.children}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="linkb/c" component={ComponentC}/>
          <Route exact path="linkb/d" component={ComponentD}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click link C or link D, the url updates in the browser bar but nothing changes on the page / the new component is not rendered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you tried `path="/linkb/c"` because you specified exact on the route component.

Comment: What does the url say at that point?

Comment: @AlexGuerra the url in the browser updates correctly, eg to `http://localhost:3000/linkb/c`. Nothing changes in the page itself and the new component isn't rendered. I just noticed that the page doesn't go blank though, i should update my Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - so the only way I've gotten this to work is to stop hardcoding the paths in my child components, and use the path segments passed in via react-router. Since these evaluate to the same thing (I think) I'm unsure why this fixes my problem, but it does:

```
      <Link to={`${this.props.match.path}/c`}>link c </Link>
      <Link to={`${this.props.match.path}/d`}>link d </Link>
```

And that works!! No idea why! If someone can explain why I'll accept their answer instead of mine.

**update**: appears to have been a case of absolute vs relative urls. Using props.match.path avoid that kind of confusion.